# Toolbar title not centered while usine Menu

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My ToolBar contains 3 components.

1. Left Image
2. Title Center
3. Menu

ToolBar title not centred when I set Menu.

I am setting visibility of the Menu dynamic based on API response.

Have a look at below.

**`ToolBar` without Menu.**

[image]

**`ToolBar` with `Menu` item Visible**

[image]

[image]

**ToolBar Code**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/blue”
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/blue”
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_icon"
                android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="mySet"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:visibility="visible />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Menu Declaration in MainActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_right_icons, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Handel Menu visibility in Different Fragment using below code**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_live).setVisible(true);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_finish).setVisible(false);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**How to set `Toolbar` title in the center while `Menu` is visible?**

Comment: Change the `<RelativeLayout>`'s `layout_width` to `wrap_content`, and add `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`, or just `"center"`.

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: Not able to use `android:layout_gravity` in RelativeLayout.

Comment: Where are you trying to put it, exactly? It goes in the opening `<RelativeLayout>` tag.

Comment: Yes There is only 1 `RelativeLayout`. I put there. But I'm not able to access `android:layout_gravity ` property there.

Comment: How do you mean, exactly? It won't autocomplete for you? Or it gives a specific error?

Comment: No specific error, It won't autocomplete.

Comment: Yeah, it's not autocompleting for me, either. Just type it out manually, or copy/paste it from my comment above.

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Yah Its working fine now. Thanks a lot. You saved me. :)